# Enable or disable custom button in ribbon in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have a custom button in ribbon in compose window of outlook. When a user clicks on it, some actions are performed.

I want to enable/disable this button when BCC is specified in compose mail window.

How to achieve this ?